# It's parallel stream method anyMatch(), allMatch(), noneMatch() allways short-circuiting?

Tags: java, parallel-processing, java-stream, short-circuiting

I've been trying to make a parallel stream performance using short-circuiting operations like allMatch, noneMatch and anyMatch, are always applicable?

Comment: Whether these operations are “always short-circuiting”, like your title is asking, or whether they are “always applicable”, are two entirely different questions. And when you ask for help, you should describe an actual problem.

Comment: I've been trying to ask if there are cases when these short circuiting operation are applicable but considering the entry values doesn't perform well.

Comment: What “entry values”?